# Remote PhantomJS driver in Junit

Tags: java, selenium, junit, phantomjs

How do i configure selenium with a remote phantomjs drive in junit? I have been trying to find a tutorial for this but had no luck. My goal is to use this for testing in spring mvc for my single page application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some trial and error I have reached the following solution. This configuration is used in the Junit test class

```
private URI siteBase;
private static PhantomJSDriverService service;
private WebDriver driver;
protected static DesiredCapabilities dCaps;

@BeforeClass
public static void createAndStartService() throws IOException  {
    service = new PhantomJSDriverService.Builder().usingPhantomJSExecutable(new File("/path/to/phantom/driver"))
            .usingAnyFreePort()
            .build();
    service.start();
}
@AfterClass
public static void stopService() throws IOException  {
    service.stop();
}

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
      siteBase = new URI("http://localhost:8080/");
      dCaps = new DesiredCapabilities();
      dCaps.setJavascriptEnabled(true);
      dCaps.setCapability("takesScreenshot", false);

      driver = new RemoteWebDriver(service.getUrl(),dCaps);
      driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}

@After
public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    driver.quit();
}
```

If you need further information comment below.

Comment: How is this used in Spring MVC controller?

Comment: Not sure exactly what you mean. This alows me to call an external (phantomjs) test driver and do functional testing of my web application made in spring. I think how ever that this could be better realized using Node.js or Ruby with testing frameworks like capybara. I learned during this exercise that running phantomjs trough JUnit can be quite in effective. Making tests take longer.

Comment: Could you please look at this question I made: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21949689/phantomjs-to-screenshot-website-div-for-spring-mvc-tomcat-and-itext-use?lq=1 ? I want to do screenshot of my webpage, where PhantomJS is fired by Java to the view. I agree, it takes longer to do :(