# PhantomJS to screenshot website div for Spring MVC, Tomcat and iText use

Tags: java, spring, selenium, itext, phantomjs

I've been introduced to the power of PhantomJS and CasperJS to take website screenshots. The article "[*Responsive Screenshots With Casper*](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/responsive-screenshots-with-casper--net-33142)" was really helpful to learn about the basics of the two technologies plus the screenshot feature.

Next is to how can this technology be used for integration with a Spring MVC application.

So far I have tried "[*Screen Capture using PhantomJS, GhostDriver, Selenium Hub*](http://tejasvijava.blogspot.com/2013/01/screen-capture-using-phantomjs.html)"'s code and combined it with the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16794722/3287503) provided in "[*Remote PhantomJS driver in Junit*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16794721/remote-phantomjs-driver-in-junit)".

What happened is that every time I run the program, I keeps having a `ClassNotFoundError` and I kept providing the missing JAR files. I ended up downloading and providing nine new JAR files in my Spring application:

- `phantomjsdriver-1.0.4.jar`
- `selenium-java-2.39.0.jar` and its source file
- `asm-all-3.3.1.jar`
- `cglib-3.1.jar`
- `commons-exec-1.2.jar`
- `guava-16.0.1.jar`
- `httpclient-4.3.2.jar`
- `httpcore-4.3.2.jar`
- `json-20140107.jar`

until the error below showed

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [spring] in context with path [/my_spring_app] threw exception [Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: class net.sf.cglib.core.DebuggingClassWriter has interface org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor as super class] with root cause
java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: class net.sf.cglib.core.DebuggingClassWriter has interface org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor as super class
```

**Should I keep trying this path just to get a screenshot of my website?** I feel like it's a losing battle based on what's going on. I'm not familiar with `PhantomJS` and can't find any legitimate tutorial or guide online for this setup. I would go back to `iText` and `JFreeCharts` if I can't make this work.

Below is the code I use within my Spring application:

```
package my_spring_app.controller;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import org.openqa.selenium.OutputType;
import org.openqa.selenium.TakesScreenshot;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriverService;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.Augmenter;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
public class MyController {

    protected final static Log logger = LogFactory
            .getLog(MyController.class);

    @RequestMapping(value = "/screenshot", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String showSupplementsPage(ModelMap model,
            HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {

        tryPhantom();

        return "screenshot";
    }

    private URI uri;
    private static PhantomJSDriverService service;
    private WebDriver webDriver;
    protected static DesiredCapabilities dCaps;

    public void tryPhantom() {

        service = new PhantomJSDriverService.Builder()
                .usingPhantomJSExecutable(new File("classpath:phantomjs.exe"))
                .usingAnyFreePort().build();
        try {
            service.start();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            uri = new URI("http://localhost:8080/");
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        dCaps = new DesiredCapabilities();
        dCaps.setJavascriptEnabled(true);
        dCaps.setCapability("takesScreenshot", true);

        webDriver = new RemoteWebDriver(service.getUrl(), dCaps);
        webDriver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        long iStart = System.currentTimeMillis();
        webDriver.get("http://localhost:8080/");

        webDriver = new Augmenter().augment(webDriver);
        File srcFile = ((TakesScreenshot) webDriver)
                .getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
        System.out.println("File:" + srcFile);
        try {
            FileUtils.copyFile(srcFile, new File("classpath:screenshots/pic.png"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Single Page Time:"
                + (System.currentTimeMillis() - iStart));

        webDriver.quit();
        service.stop();
    }

}
```

Here is a diagram of what I have in mind:

[image]

Comment: I think you are a bit confused about how you want to take screenshots of your page. I think it could be possibel for a screen shot to be rendered by the controller but a more elegant way would be having a different program generating your pdfs on command and then provide these pdfs trough the controller if that is what you want you don't really need to do it in java its far simpler to do it in ruby. Here is a guide (http://www.cherpec.com/2013/04/30/capturing-web-page-screenshots-from-ruby/)

Comment: If I understand correctly, I can make the controller execute the Ruby code (?) and then the screenshot will be saved in classpath to be read again by the controller for viewing. Am I correct?

Comment: I think it would be better if you run the ruby code one time only as it is going to take time to generate all screen shots. You could make it pregenerate all the screenshots of the webpages you are interested in. If you really need to dynamically generate screenshots you should definatley do it in JAVA. I think you need to describe what your needs are better if you want good help. What is it you want to achive?

Comment: Yes, it is dynamic unfortunately. I have a form results page (mostly reports) wherein a user can choose to output it in PDF. I want to screenshot the `div` with a `flot.js` graph and paste it in an `iText` PDF instead of doing it all over again in Java/iText.

Comment: Then I think you are doing it correctly allthough I think you really would like to make the users computer take the screenshot is there no way to do that in js and send it to the server? What you are trying will consume quite alot of sdrvef resources. Allthough I think it could work. There is also a risk the request might time out. Tge error you have seems quite un related to phantom and also I think you have quite alot of libraries there. I used only selenium jar and configured it to use the phantomjs executable. I think there might be an example on my git hub PabloK in the project below

Comment: https://github.com/PabloK/SpringRESTboilerplate/blob/master/src/test/java/com/realitylabs/event/integration/SPATestIT.java

Answer (score 2):

**Should I keep trying this path just to get a screenshot of my website?** *I feel like it's a losing battle based on what's going on.*

You are right, I think the approach of managing dependencies needs to be reconsidered, otherwise it will not be possible to make the site work. Donwloading jars manually one by one is unlikely to give good results, as there is no guarantee that the library versions are compatible with each other.

In fact the `IncompatibleClassChangeError`is a sign that the jars downloaded are **not** compatible.

Your best bet is to use Maven to donwload most of the jars automatically. By declaring only the top level jars, Maven will then download the needed dependent jars (transitive dependencies) automatically, helping reduce and in many cases eliminate library incompatibility problems.

Once you have the site up and working, it's a matter of writing some scripts in Casper.js to access a page in your local server, click some buttons to generated PDFs etc. and then take some snapshots.

There is no special integration needed with Spring MVC, for the Spring MVC application it's transparent if the site is accessed by PhantomJS or a normal browser.

Comment: How do I make a Spring controller access a phatomjs.exe because I want the manipulation to be there?